# Lagrangian method with objective function and constraints in expected value form.

Tags: integration, derivatives, probability-distributions

Im reading a paper and over last two weeks I have been involved with a mathematical calculation. It is about maximizing the principal utility under uncertainty;

max $\int G(x-s(x))f(x,a)dx $

, where $f(x,a)$ is PDF. My question is how to take derivatives, when the problem is about expected value and probability distribution. For example, in this problem the derivatives of the first constraint;

$\int [U(s(x))-V(a)]f(x,a)dx\geq \bar{H}$

,according to $x$, $s(x)$ and $a$. $\bar{H}$ is just a constant (reservation utility).

Thank you so much in advance. :)

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! You can get displayed equations by using double dollar signs instead of single dollar signs. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.